# how to increase the buffer size of bracktrace in lldb?

Tags: lldb, backtrace

When using lldb to debug a program, the program crashes and I print "bt" to backtrace. But even I scroll all the way back to the top of the screen, I still don't see the where the program is crashed because the backtrace is too large.

Comment: Are you running lldb in a terminal window?  I think this is a question about how to have a longer scroll back buffer in your terminal.  What system are you using - Mac OS X?  Linux?  What terminal?  If you're on a Mac, it's probably the built in Terminal.app.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Yousemite

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Terminal.app` on Mac OS X, you can increase the size of your scroll-back buffer by opening the Preferences window for Terminal, click on the Profiles tab, there will be a series of buttons on the right, "Text / Window / Shell / Keyboard / Advanced".  Under "Window" under "Scrollback" you can select a number of rows, or whether Terminal should limit the scrollback buffer to a number of lines.

Also, in lldb, the `bt` command accepts an argument which is the number of stack frames to show.  It sounds like it's the *first* few stack frames that you're having trouble seeing, so this is exactly what you want.  For instance, here I have `bt` only showing me the first two stack frames:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x09bd, 0x00007fff888194de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * #0: 0x00007fff888194de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    #1: 0x00007fff8881864f libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
    #2: 0x00007fff85c75b34 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
    #3: 0x00007fff85c74ffb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1371
    #4: 0x00007fff85c74858 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    #5: 0x000000010148f497 Dock`___lldb_unnamed_function2$$Dock + 1202
    #6: 0x00007fff8e7fd5c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    #7: 0x00007fff8e7fd5c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb) bt 2
* thread #1: tid = 0x09bd, 0x00007fff888194de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * #0: 0x00007fff888194de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    #1: 0x00007fff8881864f libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
(lldb)
```